# Запретить окну уменьшаться меньше содержимого

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

Как сделать так, чтобы окно не уменьшалось до размеров, при которых внутреннее содержимое начинает обрезаться?
Содержимое - любые UIElement.
Главное чтобы окно вмещало все содержимое

Comment: А почему элементы обрезаются? У них MinHeight/MinWidth установлен что ли?